# Schematron conditional validation

Tags: xml, validation, xslt, schematron

I've recently started using schematron to validate xml documents. I'm pretty impressed by it so far, but I've stumbled upon a rule that I can't get to work properly.

I've made a simple example below.

```
<iso:assert test="ns1:some-element/text() = 'false' and /ns1:same-other-element">Error message</iso:assert>
```

Basically I want to validate two things, if `ns1:some-element/text()` contains 'false', `ns1:same-other-element` should be present, and that validation actually works. However, when `ns1:some-element/text()` contains something other than false, than I don't care weather ns1:same-other-element is there or not.

At this moment, the rule also fires when ns1:same-other-element is missing and the value of `ns1:some-element/text()` is not 'false'

Any ideas how to work around this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your test needs to evaluate to true in order to pass validation (you are making an [assertion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assertion_%28computing%29) about something). What you are currently saying with your condition is: the text node of `ns1:some-element` MUST have a value of 'false' AND `ns1:some-other-element` MUST exist. Anything else is an error.

The condition you are probably looking for is

```xml
<iso:assert test="ns1:some-element = 'false' and /ns1:same-other-element or ns1:some-element != 'false'">Error message</iso:assert>
```

This condition will be true whenever `ns1:some-element` has a value that is not 'false', regardless of whether `ns1:some-other-element` is present.

Comment: Thanks, that seems indeed like the right way to go. I now got the rule working the way I wanted it to work.

Comment: A simpler, equivalent condition would be simply: `ns1:some-element != 'false' or /ns1:same-other-element`.